# odometry question

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
in the navigation stack, the publishing odometry part.
where those values should come from?
16   double vx = 0.1;
17   double vy = -0.1;
18   double vth = 0.1;

from this code:
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205760/odometry-question/) by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The paragraph below the breakdown of that line of code states:

> Here we'll set some velocities that
> will cause the "base_link" frame to
> move in the "odom" frame at a rate of
> 0.1m/s in the x direction, -0.1m/s in the y direction, and 0.1rad/s in the
> th direction. This will more or less
> cause our fake robot to drive in a
> circle.

Basically the robot will move those amounts with every time step.

`nav_msgs/odometry` messages take the following form:

```
# This represents an estimate of a position and velocity in free space.  
# The pose in this message should be specified in the coordinate frame given by header.frame_id.
# The twist in this message should be specified in the coordinate frame given by the child_frame_id
Header header
string child_frame_id
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance twist
```

You can find information concerning `geometry_msgs` [here](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs).

In a real situation, a robot driver, like `p2os` or `turtlebot`, will extract the position and velocity information (or data from the motor encoders) and will produce the `nav_msgs/odometry`.  If you have built your own robot, you will have to create a node which extracts motor encoder data and publishes the `nav_msgs/odometry`.  Take a look at other robot's `driver_nodes` for an example.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-24**:
my question is that those three variables are set in this example as an arbitrary values.
if i wanna really implement it then those values should come from a sensor or so right? where do they come from?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-24**:
Absolutely right.  Those values are an arbitrary value to demonstrate how to publish a `nav_msgs/Odometry` message over ROS and a transform using tf for a robot.

I have a Pioneer3-DX robot and the p2os_driver node takes encoder information from the robot and publishes the odom message to ROS.

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-24**:
ok so what are those encoder information exactly? what should i put in the x,y, and th from the encoder?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-24**:
Depending on your robot, there may be a driver which does that for you.

However, if you built your own, you will have to calculate your robot's odometry information.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-24**:
distance = (left_encoder + right_encoder) / 2.0

theta = (left_encoder - right_encoder) / WHEEL_BASE

X_position = distance * sin(theta)
Y_position = distance * cos(theta)

For help, take a look here: [http://www.geology.smu.edu/~dpa-www/robots/doc/odometry.txt](http://www.geology.smu.edu/%7Edpa-www/robots/doc/odometry.txt)

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-25**:
ok thank u.. my controller is Roboteq SDC21xx and yes it has a driver but I don't know how to use it. do u recommend to do it manually or do I have to learn how to use the driver sooner or later? THANK U

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-25**:
That is your controller, but what are you using for your robot platform?  Is it commercial-off-the-shelf or did you build it?  My platform is the Pioneer3-DX and it is connected to my controller (SlimPro675p) by serial connection.

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-25**:
no it is not commercial-off-the-shelf.. i got my platform from SuperDroid Robotics. and got me this controller.

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-25**:
ok do u have any idea what are the unit measures in those variables? inches/sec? radians? i guess i'll do them manually

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-25**:
Good luck.  Just keep in mind that you will have to publish the messages with the following formats:

[nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html)

[geometry_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs)

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-03-25**:
ok do u have any idea what are the unit measures in those variables? inches/sec? radians? i guess i'll do them manually

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-25**:
Position (x,y,z): meters

Orientation (x,y,z,w): radians

Velocity (x,y,z): meters/second

Orientation (x,y,z,w): radians/second